# Java chat - thread listening from server

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm trying to create a simple chat that uses thread to listen for incoming messages. I have a main class that opens up a socket to a server that at the moment just sends one message. I'm having problem listening for the incoming message though, and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

This is the main class, sorry for all the GUI code, it makes it long.

```
package def;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;


public class GUI extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;

    private static JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JMenu fileMenu;
    private JMenuItem openMenu;
    private JMenuItem exitMenu;

    private Socket socket;
    private ObjectOutputStream oos;
    private ObjectInputStream ois;

    private String ipAddress;

    private JTextArea textArea;
    private String fromServer = "";


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    GUI frame = new GUI();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public GUI() throws IOException {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 325);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        textArea = new JTextArea();
        contentPane.add(textArea, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        textArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 230));
        textArea.setEditable(false);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
                if(arg0.getKeyCode() ==java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                    // TODO
                }
            }
        });
        contentPane.add(textField, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        textField.setColumns(10);


        // Create menu item
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        openMenu = new JMenuItem("Open chat");
        openMenu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                ipAddress = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ange IP-address: ");
                try {
                    openSocket(ipAddress);
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        exitMenu = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        exitMenu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        fileMenu.add(openMenu);
        fileMenu.add(exitMenu);
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);

        setJMenuBar(menuBar); //Add the menubar
        setVisible(true);
    }

    //Open a socket to the server
    private void openSocket(String ipAddress) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        socket = new Socket(ipAddress, 1337);
        new ListenIncoming(socket, this).start();
        System.out.println("Socket and thread started!");
    }

    public void setMessage(String message){
        textArea.setText(message);
    }
}
```

There is an action listener for the "Open chat" button in the menu, where it runs the method openSocket(). In this method, found at the bottom of the code, I open a socket and starts a new ListenIncoming-thread.

This is the thread code:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ListenIncoming extends Thread{

    private Socket socket;
    private ObjectInputStream ois;
    private GUI gui;


    public ListenIncoming(Socket socket, GUI gui){
        this.socket = socket;
        this.gui = gui;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        //A loop that runs forever
        while(true){
            try {
                String fromServer = ois.readObject().toString();
                System.out.println(fromServer);
                gui.setMessage(fromServer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the server that sends one message. I expected to receive the message "Connected" but I get nothing, no error nor exception. I don't know where my code is wrong.

```
public class Server {

    private static Scanner in;
    private static String toSend;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        toSend = "";
        int port = 1337;
        in = new Scanner(System.in);


        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: " + port);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not connect.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        String input, output;

        output = "Connected!\n";
        oos.writeObject(output);
        System.out.println("This code is reached?");

        oos.close();
        ois.close();
        clientSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close();
    }
}
```

I get the printout from the GUI class when I run the program, though I don't get the debug out prints from the Server class. I'm using Eclipse, but shouldn't both classes be able to write to the console? How come I never reach that code? The problem seem to be at the server side, but wouldn't it generate some error on the client side when trying to read?

Thanks for all the tips and inputs I can get on this!

Comment: since you open two java programs there will be two output console. Did you check other output console for the server?

Comment: Isn't the firewall blocking port 1337 on the server ip you enter in the gui?

Comment: I didn't have any trouble with this earlier, only now when I'm using a different thread. Earlier I could retrieve the sent message with a while loop.

There is only one console open for me in Eclipse, how can I open another?

Thanks for the inputs!
Z!

Comment: Not really related to your problem, but it's good practice to implement `Runnable` instead of extending `Thread`.

Comment: There's one Console **view**, but it contains many console outputs at once. Did you check the buttons in its toolbar? In any case, add a simple `System.out.println` statement before actually reading from the socket to ensure you are about to see the message when it comes.

Comment: Use this button in the toolbar to switch from console: http://i48.tinypic.com/16gfiih.png

Comment: Thank you for all the inputs!
In the server console, I added the printout in the server and has come to the conclusion that the message is never sent.

Comment: It would be interesting to try and write a bunch of the objects to see if some of them come across.  I wonder if you are running into buffering somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Run the Server class first..then run you GUI class(client)

Print on console to confirm the server is started -

```
System.out.println("Server started: " + serverSocket);
```

below

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
```

The below line will wait for the client to connect to the server.

```
    socket = server.accept();
```

unless you cannot get the server message.